# Change button text without button icon change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have next button:

```js
$('.change-button-text').click(function(){
  $('.target-chooser').html('Edit target');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next target-chooser" type="button">
  Choose target
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button class="change-button-text" type="button">
  Change button text
</button>
```

How change text without losing a button icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to wrap the text in a `span`, then target that element.

Assuming you can't amend the HTML then you can use `contents()` and `filter()` to retrieve the text node, before changing it's `textContent`. Try this:

```js
$('.change-button-text').click(function() {
  $('.target-chooser').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.trim();
  })[0].textContent = 'Edit target ';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next target-chooser" type="button">
  Choose target
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button class="change-button-text" type="button">
  Change button text
</button>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `span` tag inside of your button:

```js
$('.change-button-text').click(function(){
  $('.target-chooser span').text('Edit targer');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next target-chooser" type="button" data-target-id="">
  <span>Choose target</span>
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button class="change-button-text" type="button" data-target-id="">
  Change button text
</button>
```

or if you don't want to use a `span` tag:

```js
$('.change-button-text').click(function(){
  $('.target-chooser').html('Edit targer <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next target-chooser" type="button" data-target-id="">
  Choose target
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button class="change-button-text" type="button" data-target-id="">
  Change button text
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I do that action without span?

Comment: That is better variant for this question

Answer (score 0):

Add the button text in a span and change the selector to `#selector>span` like so:

```js
$('.change-button-text').click(function(){
  $('.target-chooser>span').html('Edit targer');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next target-chooser" type="button" data-target-id="">
  <span>Choose target</span>
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button class="change-button-text" type="button" data-target-id="">
  Change button text
</button>
```

Or if you do not want to use span use the following:

```
var newText = 'Edit targer';
$('.target-chooser>span').html(newText+'<i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with JavaScript element properties. But this is not generic fix.

```
$('.target-chooser')[0].firstChild.data = 'Edit targer';
```

**Code snippet:**

```js
$('.change-button-text').click(function(){
  $('.target-chooser')[0].firstChild.data = 'Edit targer ';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next target-chooser" type="button">
  Choose target
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button class="change-button-text" type="button">
  Change button text
</button>
```

Comment: That's not good in my case cause in some situations icons can be either first or last elements

Comment: @PavloZhukov As I said in answer `this is not generic fix.` Need to update based on the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
$(.target-chooser).empty();
$(.target-chooser).append('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Edit target')
```

Here you can also change the icon itself

Comment: That's not good idea cause it require duplicate icon structure definition